# global update event for Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vue.js, is there a way to register an event if any component updates its data?

My usecase: I am modeling a RPG character via a set of Javascript classes. The `TCharacter` class has several attributes that can be modified: name, level, HP, magic. While "name" is a simple string, "HP" and "magic" is a custom class `TResource` which has its own consumption and refill rules.

Instance of the `TCharacter` class is a source of truth, and I created some Vue components that are views of it.

I created a `character` component and a `resource` component in Vue, vaguely like this:

```
<div class=template id=character>
   <input v-model="ch.name">
   <resource :attr="ch.magic"></resource>
   <resource :attr="ch.hp"></resource>
</div>

<div class="template" id="resource">
   you have {{ attr.available }} points
   <button @click="attr.consume">X</button>
</div>

<div id="main">
   <character :ch="lancelot"></character>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
class TCharacter {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Lancelot"
    this.hp = new Resource(20)
    this.magic = new Resource(10)
  }
}

class TResource {
  constructor(limit) {
    this.available = limit
    this.limit = limit
  }

  consume() {
    if (this.available > 0) this.available--;
  }
}

let lancelot = new TCharacter()

Vue.component('character', {
  template: '#character',
  props: ['ch'],
})

Vue.component('resource', {
  template: '#resource',
  props: ['attr'],
})

new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data() { return { lancelot } }
})
```

(I'm not sure the code works exactly as written, but hopefully the intent is clear. Something very similar to this is already working for me.)

Now, I'd like to **save the character object** to localstorage every time the user makes a modification: changes its name, clicks on a button that consumes a point of magic, etc.

So for instance, I want to be notified that the value of `ch.name` changed because the user typed something into the input box. Or that a magic point was lost because the user clicked a button for that.

I could detect changes to the `character` component by installing an `updated()` handler, which notifies me whenever a DOM is modified ([viz](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated)). However, this won't trigger when the child component `resource` is modified. I'd need to add a separate `updated()` handler to all other components. This gets tedious very fast.

I'm imagining something like a global `updated()` handler that would fire any time *any component* has registered a change. Or better, a way to specify that `update` should fire on component's children changes as well.

edit: I have reworded parts of the question to clarify what I'm trying to accomplish.
Some of you already suggested Vuex. But, from what I understood, Vuex enforces being the single source of truth -- I already *have* a single source of truth. How is Vuex different / better?

Comment: Show the `Resource` class. What about it is not automatically updating?

Comment: This is an unusual reuse of vue components. They are designed to be visual elements, and they compose the view. The whole component is not meant to be an abstract element of business or even presentation logic.

What you aught to do is separate your concerns: You have data that is consumed in various places and presented at least primarily (lets say) in a Character component. That state should be saved and maintained in a central place, like a vuex store module called "character". The transactions with that data are vuex actions, which should ensure consistency of data.

Comment: @robertotomás I don't understand. Why is component not "abstract element of presentation logic"? I am trying to write the components as thin wrappers on top of my object model - is Vue the wrong tool for that job?

Comment: vue is definitely the wrong tool for the job of saving game state.  It is the right tool to present game state.  you need to separate your concerns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a serialized version of `lancelot` to write out. You can do that with a [`computed`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#ad). Then you can `watch` the computed to see when anything changes.

Alternatively, you *could* `watch` each individual trait, and write it out as it changes.

```js
class TCharacter {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Lancelot"
    this.hp = new TResource(20)
    this.magic = new TResource(10)
  }
}

class TResource {
  constructor(limit) {
    this.available = limit
    this.limit = limit
  }

  consume() {
    if (this.available > 0) this.available--;
  }
}

let lancelot = new TCharacter()

Vue.component('character', {
  template: '#character',
  props: ['ch'],
})

Vue.component('resource', {
  template: '#resource',
  props: ['attr'],
})

const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data() {
    return {
      lancelot
    }
  },
  computed: {
    serializedLancelot() {
      return JSON.stringify(this.lancelot);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    serializedLancelot(newValue) {
      console.log("Save update:", newValue);
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  vm.lancelot.hp.consume();
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="main">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure I understand the use case in entirety, but if my assumption is right, you need to update components based on an object's update (updates to properties of an object), for that you could use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) . Although am not sure if you are restricted to use an additional library

Here as an example, you could add a state value named `character` which is an `object`, something along the lines of

```
const state = {
 character = {}; 
}
```

And now you can mutate this using vuex [mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html).

```
commit('set_character', your_new_value)
```

Now since you said you need to update all or some components based on any mutation to character, use vuex [plugins](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/plugins.html) to listen to any mutation to that object, and update the state of the components.

```
 store.subscribe(mutation => {
  if (mutation.type === 'set_character') {
    // do whatever you want here
  }
})
```

All of the above is just an outline based on what you mentioned, but this is just a starter, you may or may not want to add `character` into the store's state but simply the properties such as `magic` or `hp`.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified the question based on your comment, to explain better what I'm trying to do and what is not working for me. I was looking into Vuex, but ISTM it's mostly solving the "single source of truth" problem at the cost of significantly more boilerplate code.
If you could explain why Vuex is useful for me and how it helps, that would be great.

Comment: Two main advantages that i can think of right away is -> as you already mentioned single source of truth sort of or in other words if the data is shared across components and also this would avoid `props` hell. else you got pass props all over and or repeat your `watch` on the props property. that said, not sure what you mean by more boilerplate code -> unless you want to split your store in different modules etx, its as simple as wiring up vuex and using the store's state, mutations and actions. not necessarily all